# how to solve my API connection error via Angular?

Tags: node.js, angular, api, get

I have started to develop a website with Angular and NodeJS but I am facing a problem since a few days.
(For information: I work on a VPS which is external)
So my site is running on port 4200 of the IP of my VPS and is secured via a domain name in HTTPS, so I try to make a request to my API which is running on port 3000 of my VPS but when I put "http://localhost:3000/api/commands" I have the attached error in my web console.
Thank you in advance for your help! [Image of my error in my web console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxFtQ.png)

EDIT : If I replace localhost with the ip of my VPS, I get a "Mixed Content" error

Comment: Does the error message show anything else? e.g., `CORS`?

Comment: I also have an "HTTPerrorResponse" error